# Change ouput url of WordPress [Gallery] Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I recently installed ta plugin that now uploads my images from the media library to s3.

I have also FTP's the entire uploads folder to s3 which encompasses about 4000 images.

I have used throughout my site the wordpress gallery shortcode however somewhere and somehow it outputs the siteurl.

How do I change this so that I can override the url to be the one from my S3 bucket?

I will admit I have no idea what I am doing here or where to start and I really will appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you update with which plugin have you installed? I think there are many for accomplishing this task. Some plugins do not support files when directly being uploaded to S3.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter images src attribute output and replace old url with new url as follow. copy below code to your theme `functions.php` and replace `www.oldurl.com` and `www.newurl.com` with your own urls.

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', function ($image) {
    if(is_array($image)){
        $image[0] = str_replace('www.oldurl.com', 'www.newurl.com', $image[0]);
    }

    return $image;
}, 999);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the [`wp_get_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_upload_dir/), that's a wrapper for [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/), that's again wrapper for [`_wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_upload_dir/), we see that the upload url can be modified through the `upload_url_path` option.

Since you're moving all of your uploads to S3, you could try to add your S3 bucket base url into the `upload_url_path` option.

You should test this first on your dev install, just to see how it works with your current setup.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make a search & replace via the database.

You can see here how to make a SQL Query to change the Image Path in the posts: [13 Useful WordPress Queries](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/)

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'src="http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Comment: Already considered this. However, the URL which is used for the gallery shortcode is the same reference used for the site URL. So, if I changed it, the images would work but then the site would break. Catch 22